# How to set text limit for attributed text UILabel in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I would like to know that is it possible to limit the attributed text length for UILabel? I have added label in my custom UITableViewCell. Actually i am doing Letter Spacing for UILabel text using my below code, now i need to set text length for the same.

here is my code :

```
cell.lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cabin-SemiBold" size:15.0f];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:notifi.notificationData];

float spacing = 1.5f;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@(spacing)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [notifi.notificationData length])];

cell.lblTitle.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Using this code i am getting output as below image 1 :

[image]

But my output should be like this below image 2 (Need to display limited text for every title in table row) :

[image]

Can you please suggest me how can i achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: You want you string to be limited in length? Then why not just substring the string to the maximum number of charaters you want or make the `UILabel` smaller and turn the font scaling off.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenesYeah, i want limited length of title text. how can i make font scaling off, if possible can you please change in my code?

Comment: Read the [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) documentation.

Comment: @rckoenesI have added "notifi.notificationData = [notifi.notificationData substringToIndex:23];" before my code, Its working. Thanks!